# "Copy-Paste" data validation from different source in Apache POI Excel

Tags: java, excel, validation, apache-poi

I have created an excel file with dropdown using Apache POI. The below is the code:

```
{
row.createCell(i).setCellValue(col[i]); //i -- loop counter
CellRangeAddressList addressList = new CellRangeAddressList(1, 1000, i, i); 
DVConstraint dvConstraint = DVConstraint.createExplicitListConstraint( new String[]{"10", "20", "30"});
DataValidation dataValidation = new HSSFDataValidation(addressList, dvConstraint);
dataValidation.setSuppressDropDownArrow(false);
sheet.addValidationData(dataValidation);
}
```

This code does the validation of the data when we have entered manually. If i enter value = 40 in the cell (that i generated) manually, it throws an error.

But the issue comes when i try to copy the value = 40 from some different place and then pasting the value in the same cell (excel). It works !! How do i validate "copy-paste" of the data value (from different source) in the excel dropdown.

Please kindly help in this. I am clueless. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're creating a new cell but you're not defining its type (CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC in your case). Could this be a problem?

Comment: No i dont think that is the problem. Even with definining the cellType , copy pasting values will pass the validation.

Comment: I think this answers your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36568376/data-validation-fails-when-copy-pasting-data-in-excel-made-through-apache-poi