# Data validation fails when copy pasting data in excel made through apache poi

Tags: java, excel, apache, validation

I am making one .xls file using apache poi. I'm including some data validations also as shown.

```
ObservableList<String> objectstatusList = UpgradeWorkBench.wsData.getObjectStatusDevMan("Test", "testing");
String[] strStatus = new String[objectstatusList.size()];
objectstatusList.toArray(strStatus);

CellRangeAddressList addressListStatus = new CellRangeAddressList(0, 65535, 9, 9);
DVConstraint dvConstraintStatus = DVConstraint.createExplicitListConstraint(strStatus);
dataValidationStatus = new HSSFDataValidation(addressListStatus, dvConstraintStatus);
dataValidationStatus.setSuppressDropDownArrow(false);
dataValidationStatus.setErrorStyle(ErrorStyle.STOP);
```

The validation is applied correctly if I enter any data manually. But if I copy paste data from some other cell the validation fails, also the validation gets completely removed from that cell. Can anyone please help on how can i validate data even on copy paste.

I saw many links but couldnt get the correct solution

Comment: "But if I copy paste data from some other cell the validation fails, also the validation gets completely removed from that cell." This is not dependent on apache poi. The same will also occur with native Excel. See http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/ensuring_that_data_validation_is_not_deleted/.

Comment: I have to control the excel using java only. How can I do that?

Comment: Since `apache poi` cannot create macros, you cannot do this directly. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since `apache poi` cannot create macros, the only way is to have a template with the needed macro and creating the result from that template.

Example:

Have a `template.xls` with a worksheet `Sheet1` and the macro from http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/ensuring_that_data_validation_is_not_deleted/  located in the code module for that worksheet.

Edit 2020-09-03:
The above link is dead now. But see https://superuser.com/questions/870926/restrict-paste-into-dropdown-cells-in-excel. There the used name is "DataValidationRange" instead of "ValidationRange". This would must be considered.

Then you could use following code:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataValidation.ErrorStyle;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*;

import java.io.*;

class ReadAndWriteFromTemplateWithMacro {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {

   String templateName = "template.xls";
   String resultName = "result.xls";
 
   String sheetName = "Sheet1";
 
   String[] strStatus = new String[]{"on", "off", "maybe"};

   FileInputStream template = new FileInputStream(templateName);
   Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(template);   
   Sheet sheet = wb.getSheet(sheetName);

   if (sheet instanceof HSSFSheet) {

    CellRangeAddressList addressListStatus = new CellRangeAddressList(0, 65535, 9, 9);  
    DVConstraint dvConstraint = DVConstraint.createExplicitListConstraint(strStatus);
    DataValidation dataValidation = new HSSFDataValidation(addressListStatus, dvConstraint);
    dataValidation.setSuppressDropDownArrow(false);
    dataValidation.setErrorStyle(ErrorStyle.STOP);

    sheet.addValidationData(dataValidation);

    //create a named range for the data validation as described in http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/ensuring_that_data_validation_is_not_deleted/
    Name name =  wb.createName();
    name.setNameName("ValidationRange");
    String reference = addressListStatus.getCellRangeAddress(0).formatAsString(sheetName, true);
    name.setRefersToFormula(reference);

   }

   FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(resultName);
   wb.write(output);
   wb.close();

  } catch (InvalidFormatException ifex) {
  } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfex) {
  } catch (IOException ioex) {
  }
 }
}
```

Now the `result.xls` will contain that macro also. If macros are enabled, then this macro will prevent destroy data valitation by pasting over.

Comment: What do you mean by 'putting the macro in code module'??? Where should the macro be placed?

Comment: The worksheet code module can be found in VBA editor as described here (http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/code.htm) for example. Another way to go to a sheet module is to right click on a sheet tab and choose "View Code".