# BLOCK the use of PASTE in EXCEL (Java and org.apache.poi)

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, paste

**JAVA + POI** > Is there a way to unable/block the System / Excel PASTE command. Or give an ERROR and refuse like while typing a manual input.

I build this Excel file with Java 8 and org.apache.poi (perhaps another library will work).

**I implemented all kinds of RESTRICTIONS and VALIDATION:**

```
constraint =validationHelper.createExplicitListConstraint(new String[]{"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"});
addressList = new  CellRangeAddressList(0,999,0,0);
dataValidation = validationHelper.createValidation(constraint, addressList);
dataValidation.setShowErrorBox(true);
sheet.addValidationData(dataValidation);
```

**I have inplemented all kinds of LOCKING:**

```
sheet.lockObjects(true);
sheet.lockDeleteColumns(true); 
sheet.lockDeleteRows(true); 
sheet.lockFormatCells(true); 
sheet.lockFormatColumns(true); 
sheet.lockFormatRows(true); 
sheet.lockInsertColumns(true); 
sheet.lockInsertRows(true); 
sheet.enableLocking();

workbook.lockStructure();
```

But is is still possible to paste whatever you want in the cell with a Paste from the memory. Even when i lock the Drop Down restrictions with:

```
Name name =  workbook.createName();
name.setNameName("ValidationRange");
String reference = addressList.getCellRangeAddress(0).formatAsString("SHEET", true);
name.setRefersToFormula(reference);
```

Help would be great and secure Excel as an save communication tool in my JavaFX application =^)

Comment: Would a VBA `Worksheet.SelectionChange` macro to clear the clipboard solve the problem?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37802988/apache-poi-how-to-restrict-the-user-to-clear-the-data-validations-in-excel-she/37817030#37817030, "Excel as an save communication tool": No, it is not. `Excel` is *one* possible data *export* format. But to rely on `Excel` as data input source or data exchange format? You should not do this. Surely only my humble opinion.

Comment: Hi @jsheeran and Axel Richter Thanks for the comments. People in my line of work are addicted to Excel for data collection, communication and reporting. I like and hate Excel at the same time. It is a powerful but extremely sloppy tool, but anyway we have to find a way to handle it in the best way and integrate it with their way of working =^). The copy paste happens while the sheet is open so if i clear it on start the harm will still be done. Perhaps jsheeran you can share some code or a macro that could work so i can test it.

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix is to define a macro in the worksheet which, when the user selects a cell on that worksheet, will copy to the clipboard the contents of a cell which is known to be empty:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  [XFD1048576].Copy
End Sub
```

Note that this might annoy the user, since it'll empty the clipboard regardless of whether they'd intended to paste something into a cell or otherwise. It's also easily circumvented if the user chooses to disable macros or to save as .xlsx.

Comment: I will try to create this in Java in a way that the user can not refuse the script and than give the solution i found here =^)